# Why there is no VSS for sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, volume-shadow-service

The SQL Server implementation by Microsoft contains the VSS writer and other components with it to help it take backups without making a considerable impacy on performance.
But there is no such VSS capability built into Sqlite.
So I would like understand the importance of VSS in SQL Server and how it can be useful for Sqlite?

Comment: I don't really get how visual source safe could improve performance of backup of sql servers. Sqlite isn't written by microsoft and it's unlikely that such feature would be added in the future. SQlite is supposed to lock the databases on write. So if you have many users doing parallels write, you should simply consider a different database that supports replication instead.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix He's referring to Volume Shadow Service, which maintains point-in-time "versions" of on-disk data to allow things like live backups.   But you're right in the sense that programs that use it need to integrate pretty deeply with it.

Answer (score 0):

VSS is a mechanism for achieving high concurrency.

SQLite [is not designed for high concurrency](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) in the first place.

(That said, in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), it is possible to make a backup without affecting other readers and writers, and even without WAL, the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) has a mechanism to restart the backup if another writer would have made it inconsistent.)